# Get the url on a webview and paste automatically (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a button on a webview app that get the url from the current Page.  I would like to paste it automatically on my website(with another button or the same). How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome To SO, Provide your attempt to solve this matter

Answer (score 0):

I only write this to get the url

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Button");
  //  button.setId(1);

    final WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    webview.addView(button);
    setContentView(webview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String webUrl = webview.getUrl();
            webview.loadUrl(webUrl);
    }
    });








    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);          
    final Activity activity = this;
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    });

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("http://...../");          


}
```